# Invalid VkSurfaceKHR handle from QtWidget/QtWindow

Tags: qt, vulkan

I try to create a valid VkSurfaceKHR surface object in a Qt 5.10.1 C++ application on Ubuntu Linux 18.04 for a QWidget derived class. The code for obtaining the vulkan instance and surface looks like this:

```
QVulkanInstance inst;

inst.setLayers(QByteArrayList() << "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation");

if (!inst.create())
   qFatal("Failed to create Vulkan instance: %d", inst.errorCode());


   …  A QtWidget is created. code is omitted …

widget->show();

QWindow* realWindow = widget->windowHandle();

if ( !realWindow && widget->nativeParentWidget() )
    realWindow = widget->nativeParentWidget()->windowHandle();

realWindow->setSurfaceType ( QSurface::VulkanSurface );
realWindow->setVulkanInstance ( &inst );

m_VulkanSurface = QVulkanInstance::surfaceForWindow ( realWindow );
```

After successfully creating a vulcan instance and creating a device from it, I get a segfault in a vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR call with this surface albeit surfaceForWindow doesn't return 0.

Shortly before the crash I get these error messages from VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation_layer:

```
vkDebug: Validation: 0: Validation Error: [ VUID-vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR-surface-parameter ] Object 0: VK_NULL_HANDLE, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_INSTANCE; | MessageID = 0x801f247e | Invalid VkSurfaceKHR Object 0x55555777b560. The Vulkan spec states: surface must be a valid VkSurfaceKHR handle (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.154.0/linux/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR-surface-parameter)

vkDebug: Validation: 0: Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-Threading-Info ] Object 0: handle = 0x55555777b560, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_SURFACE_KHR; | MessageID = 0x5d6b67e2 | Couldn't find VkSurfaceKHR Object 0x55555777b560. This should not happen and may indicate a bug in the application.
```

Is my method for generating a Vulkan surface on Qt applicable?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed

```
 realWindow->show();
```

It worked for me with the code below:

```
    realWindow->setSurfaceType(QSurface::VulkanSurface);
    realWindow->show();
    realWindow->setVulkanInstance(&inst);
    surface = inst.surfaceForWindow(realWindow);
```